# OCI A1.Flex Free Tier Limit Exceeded

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Oracle Cloud always free allows the creation of a 4CPU/24GB instance. I had one up and decided to put it down and start a fresh one. Then I got the famous "Out of Host Capacity".  I understand that they can't guarantee that there is enough resources, so I decided to keep trying both on CLI and on GUI. Sometimes in the middle of the "Out of Host Capacity" I get the "Limit Exceeded" error, does it means that when there is some host capacity they have tried to create this instance and fail because I was over the limit or is it just a bug? Because I have no A1.Flex up. Looking up some similar issues, I reviewed some things, it isn't trying to create a new VCN or subnet and I have more than enough boot volume available. Also I've tried to put up a 3CPU/18GB and also got the "Limit Exceeded" error, and I also have tried to assign a public IP and not assign a public IP. It's also good to mention that I can't try another availability-domain because in this tenancy, it's the only one.

This is the code I'm running every 5 minutes:

```
--availability-domain fczk:SA-SAOPAULO-1-AD-1 \
--compartment-id {mycompartment} \
--shape VM.Standard.A1.Flex \
--subnet-id {mysubnet} \
--assign-private-dns-record true \
--availability-config {myconfigfile} \
--display-name {chosenname} \
--image-id ocid1.image.oc1.sa-saopaulo-1.aaaaaaaawohyyavvqh2xxi44dwsu2ysqamht2yj54hynxv2bdhltdby6i7xq \
--instance-options {myoptionsfile} \
--shape-config {myshapefile} \
--ssh-authorized-keys-file {mypubkey} \
--boot-volume-size-in-gbs 100
```

Files:

- availability-config: {"recoveryAction": "RESTORE_INSTANCE"}
- instance-options: { "areLegacyImdsEndpointsDisabled": false}
- shape-config: {"ocpus": 4, "memoryInGBs": 24}

Most of the time I receive the "Out of Host Capacity", but sometimes I get this error:

```
    "code": "LimitExceeded",
    "message": "The following service limits were exceeded: standard-a1-memory-count, standard-a1-memory-regional-count, standard-a1-core-count, standard-a1-core-regional-count. Request a service limit increase from the service limits page in the console. . Please visit https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/References/apierrors.htm to learn more about this error code",
    "opc-request-id": "839FA3FA7C704F2C975483E6088BBACA/19443406DCB8C46F14B5D2306D5EDFEE/97188E378DFB5414ED8D711127B279A8",
    "status": 400
}
```

[limits 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpqMM.png)

[limits 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gw1t.png)

Now I just feel dumb in trying to get a fresh instance... lol

Answer (score 3):

Check your boot volumes. If you deleted a Compute instance without removing the Boot Volume, it seems to count against your limits without being reflected in the limits portal.

https://cloud.oracle.com/block-storage/boot-volumes

Comment: Perfect! My account as with 4 volumes, I deleted all and now I can create new instances! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All cloud calls are asynchronous, and the limits in Compute are deducted when you launch the instance. The "Out of Host" capacity of the previous launch hasn't returned, and that is why the "limit" error shows up.

Comment: Thank you, I increased the interval to 10 minutes now. Still no luck... Is there something to do? Maybe some config... Or just keep trying?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you get "out of host capacity", then there are no instances free. You essentially have to wait till someone else terminates an instance.